# How to make a Photo Guess Game using HTML5 or any free tools?

Tags: html

I'm preparing a photo guess game in a party. We would like to pick out a few photos of scenery in different countries and let the guests to guess where they are. We would like to cut the picture into (e.g. 16 pieces). Each time we click on one of the pieces and let the guests to guess, until someone can get the correct answer.

May I know is there any free tools to do this? Could we use HTML5 to do this? Any samples for this? A simple one which can manage to do this is enough. No need to be too fancy.

I have tried to search on the web to see if there is any tutorial to do this, but in vain. Please help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: I would suggest you to see at GameMakerStudio. It is HTML5 game engine with a lot of tutorials